# Calculation "invents" new solutions

Tags: powershell

I experienced a strange behavior in one of my powershell scripts.
I use this during that script:

```
$GUI_ProgressBar.Value = (($n)/($f_count*$d_count*$w_count)*100)
$n++
Write-Host "f_count= "$f_count
Write-Host "d_count= "$d_count
Write-Host "w_count= "$w_count
Write-Host "Bruch= "($f_count*$d_count*$w_count)
Write-Host "n= "$n
```

The output of that part (after several loops) is:

```
f_count=  1
d_count=  17
w_count=  6
Bruch=  111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
n=  52
```

The code works just fine when directly used in the shell.

Any ideas why "Bruch" is this off?

Comment: Looks like $f_count is [string]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to partner with ChristopherW's answer, since he is right, you can see the difference here. Like he said the value on the left hand side determines how the operator is treated.

```powershell
PS C:\Windows\system32> "5" * 5            # 5 is a string since it is in quotes
55555

PS C:\Windows\system32> [int]"5" * 5       # 5 is a number since it was cast as one.
25

PS C:\Windows\system32> $f_count.GetType().Fullname
System.String
```

Lastly if you looked at the type of `$f_count` the response you would have gotten is `System.String` which would explain what you were seeing.

Comment: Yes, f_count IS a string ... figured it out myself, but thanks for the hints :)
Additionally I will add the "Lastly if you looked at the type of $f_count the response you would have gotten is System.String which would explain what you were seeing."-part to my defaut debug query :D

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like `$f_count` may be a string. Reference [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/01/29/multiply-powershell-strings-to-customize-text-underlines.aspx) as this is actually a feature of PowerShell. If the left-hand operator is a string being multiplied by an int on the right-hand, the string is duplicated the number of times as the value of the right-hand operator.

If you need $f_count to be a string in some areas but for this particular requirement need it to be of an `int` value, either cast it (`[int]$f_count`) or you add a plus to the variable which will also convert it to an int (`+$f_count`)